# Sample tabular dataset for power bi

Tags: powerbi, reportbuilder3.0, tabular-editor

I am a newbie to power bi and trying to find a complete sample dataset model of powerbi in the following format to deploy to the Power BI workspace.

Can someone help me in providing or pointing to how/where can I get sample files in the following format please.

[image: PBIDataset]

Again I need a complete set to add to my repository,  so I can create an artifact of the tabular model and deploy it to power bi workspace from my dev ops pipeline  as a dataset please.

Thanks much